# PHP/XML Delete Child in image Sitemap

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have a XML image Sitemap for google like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.domain.de</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>http://www.domain.de/image1.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:title>image 1</image:title>
        </image:image>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>http://www.domain.de/image2.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:title>image 2</image:title>
        </image:image>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Now I will delete a "image:image" child where "image:loc" is like "http://www.domain.de/image2.jpg".
How can I do this with php?

I have tested code like the following:

```
$xmlPageUrl="http://www.domain.de/image2.jpg";    
foreach($sitemap->xPath('//url[image:image/image:loc="' . $xmlPageUrl . '"]') as $node) {
      $sitemap->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `text()` in xpath to search for specific content :

```xml
//image:image/image:loc[text()="http://www.domain.de/image2.jpg"]
```

so :

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$xmlPageUrl="http://www.domain.de/image2.jpg";    

foreach($xpath->query('//image:image/image:loc[text()="'.$xmlPageUrl.'"]') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($node->parentNode);
}
```

the XML now contains :

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.domain.de</loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>http://www.domain.de/image1.jpg</image:loc>
            <image:title>image 1</image:title>
        </image:image>

    </url>
</urlset>
```